# How to get the value of text box without a button in PHP?

Tags: php, html-table

I need a table that have condition that the `fullyy = $ddate` how will I get the value of the `ddate` textbox and put it to the variable `$ddate` I have. I need this code in the same page:

```
//php
$ddate = "";
  if (isset($_POST['ddate']))
    { $ddate = $_POST['ddate'];

 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblnpatient WHERE fullyy = '$ddate'");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['pnum'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['pname'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['addr'].'</td>';
}}
```

This is my html, the value of `ddate` is from a script:

```
  Diff:<input name="ddate" id="ddate"  />
```

There is no result in my page, what is wrong in my code?

Comment: your title is weird it doesn't match the problem you state in your question, maybe your query yielded 0 results, what is `fullyy` column anyway? is that date? and what do you input on the textbox?, maybe thats the reason there is no output

Comment: the fully column is a text

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a form. It should look something like this:

```
<?php
    $ddate = "";
    if (isset($_POST['ddate'])){
        $ddate = $_POST['ddate'];
    }
?>
```

and you should use `mysqli_` instead of `mysql_`:

```
<?php
    $results = mysqli_query($connection, $query);   

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)){
        echo "<br/>";
        echo $row["name"];
    }
    mysqli_free_result($result);
?>
```

and your form should look something like this:

```
<form action="samefile.php" method="post">
      Diff:<input type="text" name="ddate" id="ddate" onchange"this.form.submit()"/> 
</form>
```

Comment: and if you're using a php variable inside of a string user the `"some variable is {$var}"` syntax

Comment: the value of my ddate is in the onload

Comment: Let me get this straight, your variable $ddate is posted into the page and then you are trying to change the value to whatever the value of the text box is?

Comment: no, i have a script that will give the value of the textbox when it is onload, and i need to get that value and compare it to my query

Comment: Can you please post that script?

Comment: <script>
 
        function add_date() {
     var today = new Date();
    var dd = today.getDate();
    var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!

    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
  document.getElementById("ndate").value = yyyy;
     dddd = parseInt(yyyy) -5;
 document.getElementById("ddate").value = dddd;
}
 </script>